# A method to Extract Output of Oracle Coherence Cache (CohQl) into a flat file

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle-coherence

Do we have any way to extract output of a query into a flat file, while working with CohQl, I know we have the way to do that with RDBMS databases. Something like in MySql

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

I just want it into a flat file, delimiter is not a preference, if I get a solutuion with a delimiter, well and good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix we can do something like this

./query.sh -s -c -l "select * from 'cacheObject'" >>cacheObject.txt

Comment: This answer does actually work. And with little filename swap to `query.cmd`, it should be working in Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in capability to do that.

Comment: any approach, which will let me extract the data, would be helpful. If you have used any such approach.

Comment: If you have advanced Java programming skills, I would suggest extending com.tangosol.coherence.dslquery.QueryPlus and calling the query() method, passing your query and a PrintWriter that goes to your CSV file: "protected Object query(String q, PrintWriter out, boolean trace, boolean fvalidateName, boolean fsanity)"

Comment: Thanks. That shall be helpful. Will try it by developing a Java Utility.